# The network request failed because of a connectivity error

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I was trying to connect my own server with Signal iOS app (https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS). I changed the textSecureServerURL in TSConstants.h File. But while running app i am getting this error:

```
2019-11-24 00:53:50:154 Signal[17277:122961]  [OnboardingPhoneNumberViewController.swift:309 nextPressed()]: 
2019-11-24 00:53:50:211 Signal[17277:123048]  [PushRegistrationManager.swift:59 requestPushTokens()]: 
2019-11-24 00:53:50:212 Signal[17277:122961]  [PushRegistrationManager.swift:142 registerUserNotificationSettings()]: registering user notification settings
2019-11-24 00:53:50:217 Signal[17277:123456]  [UserNotificationsAdaptee.swift:87 registerNotificationSettings()]: succeeded.
2019-11-24 00:53:50:217 Signal[17277:122961]  [AccountManager.swift:116 getPreauthChallenge(recipientId:)]: Push not supported: Push not supported on simulators
2019-11-24 00:53:50:219 Signal[17277:123048]  [TSNetworkManager.m:316 -[TSNetworkManager makeRequestSync:completionQueue:success:failure:]]: Making Non-UD request: <TSRequest: 0x7b100013d340> { URL: v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios }
2019-11-24 00:53:50:323 Signal[17277:123456]  [TSNetworkManager.m:394 +[TSNetworkManager logCurlForTask:]]: curl for failed request: curl -v -k -X GET -H 'User-Agent: Signal/2.45.1 (iPhone; iOS 12.4; Scale/2.00)' -H 'Accept-Language: en;q=1' https://api.paddytalk.com/v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios
2019-11-24 00:53:50:324 Signal[17277:123456]  [TSNetworkManager.m:433 +[TSNetworkManager handleNetworkFailure:request:task:error:]]: The network request failed because of a connectivity error: <TSRequest: 0x7b100013d340> { URL: v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios }
2019-11-24 00:53:50:327 Signal[17277:122961] ❤️ [OnboardingController.swift:463 requestVerification(fromViewController:isSMS:)]: Error: taskError(task: LocalDataTask <680D0AD8-D589-499A-A0E1-757D7281BC2E>.<1>, underlyingError: Error Domain=SignalServiceKit.TSNetworkManager Code=0 "Signal was unable to connect to the internet. Please try again." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000c42f0 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000c0f60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <680D0AD8-D589-499A-A0E1-757D7281BC2E>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <680D0AD8-D589-499A-A0E1-757D7281BC2E>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.paddytalk.com/v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.paddytalk.com/v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Signal was unable to connect to the internet. Please try again., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check if you are online and try again.})
2019-11-24 00:53:50:378 Signal[17277:122961] ❤️ [OnboardingController.swift:492 requestingVerificationDidFail(viewController:error:)]: unexpected error: Error Domain=SignalServiceKit.NetworkManagerError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000f1b60 {Error Domain=SignalServiceKit.TSNetworkManager Code=0 "Signal was unable to connect to the internet. Please try again." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000c42f0 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000c0f60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo=0x7b100011bd00 (not displayed)}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <680D0AD8-D589-499A-A0E1-757D7281BC2E>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <680D0AD8-D589-499A-A0E1-757D7281BC2E>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.paddytalk.com/v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.paddytalk.com/v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Signal was unable to connect to the internet. Please try again., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check if you are online and try again.}}}
Fatal error: [OnboardingController.swift:492 requestingVerificationDidFail(viewController:error:)]: unexpected error: Error Domain=SignalServiceKit.NetworkManagerError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000f1b60 {Error Domain=SignalServiceKit.TSNetworkManager Code=0 "Signal was unable to connect to the internet. Please try again." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000c42f0 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0c000c0f60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo=0x7b100011bd00 (not displayed)}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <680D0AD8-D589-499A-A0E1-757D7281BC2E>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <680D0AD8-D589-499A-A0E1-757D7281BC2E>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.paddytalk.com/v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.paddytalk.com/v1/accounts/sms/code/+8801731923407?client=ios, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Signal was unable to connect to the internet. Please try again., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check if you are online and try again.}}}: file /Users/istiak/iOffice/Signal-iOS/Pods/SignalCoreKit/SignalCoreKit/src/OWSSwiftUtils.swift, line 35
```

am I missing anything?

Comment: It looks like you need to specify an SSL certificate. Check this thread: https://community.signalusers.org/t/ios-app-not-working-with-self-hosted-signal-server/5693/2

Comment: is there any documentation like how to use own server and the client is signal iOS?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would ask the question in the forum, someone might be able to help you.